# C++ How to write incrementally to a file with filepointers

Tags: c++, file, serialization

I have to write a map to a file. I have a serializer and serialize the map to json. Then I want to write the map to a file.

Here is my problem: I want to create so called Keyframes to find elements in the map faster. My keyframes are a second map, which have have certain keys of the first map as keys and the adress of where this entry is saved on the harddrive as value.

This means I have to write the entries of the map incrementally and save the current "filepointer"(?) so i can create the Keyframes.

How do I write incrementally and how do I get the current filepointer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `std::ostream` to write your files, you can get the file write position using [tellp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/tellp/).

You write to the file using the normal `<<` notation. I have no idea what you mean by "incrementally"? All files are written a bit at a time, which you could call incrementally, and you can write whatever you like into them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is that I get only one Json Object for the map and I cant just write the entire JSON object to a file. I need to iterate through the keys and write every entry of the map "incrementally". My problem is that the map is already serialized, so I guess I have to split the JSON Object

Comment: Oh, "incrementally" means you want to write the difference between two JSON records? Well, that's out of scope for stack-overflow. If you have a specific question to resolve I'm sure you can post a question, with code, and somebody will help you.